# SQL Server SMO, shoud I invoke refresh everytime I modified something?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I'm playing with SMO and tried to use it to change the database owners to `sa`. The code is

```
# To simplify our discussing, let's say we have a function Get-SMOServer
$s = Get-SMOServer -Instance myserver\myinstance
$s.databases | ?{$_.owner -ne "sa"} | %{$_.setowner("sa", $true)}
```

At this point, when I check the database owners from SSMS, the owners were already changed. However, if I check it from `$s.databases`, I still got the old data, until I do something like:

```
$s.databases | %{$_.refresh()}
```

Then I can get the correct result from `$s.databases`.
I checked the SMO objects and found many of them have a `refresh()` function. My question is, should I call `refresh()` every time I modified some object? How to find all object types that have a `refresh()` member?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the SMO assembly. I'm using SMO which ships with 2008 R2:

```
$assm = add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" -EA Stop -PassThru

$assm | %{$hasRefreshMethod = $null; $hasRefreshMethod = $_.GetMethods() | ?{$_.name -eq "Refresh"}; new-object psobject -property @{Name=$_.Name; HasRefreshMethod=$($hasRefreshMethod -ne $null)}}
```